# Simile in French when gender/numbers differ

Tags: accord, genre

When we compare things using adjectives, we make sure the adjective agrees in gender and number with the noun. Here masculin pluriel:

`Les yeux sont verts`

However we say, allowing for some poetic license regarding the color itself, here in féminin singulier:

`La mer est verte`

If we wish to compare ''la mer'''with ''les yeux'', how do we perform the agreement?

```
Les yeux sont aussi vert que la mer
Les yeux sont aussi verte que la mer
Les yeux sont aussi vertes que la mer
Les yeux sont aussi verts que la mer
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Les yeux sont aussi verts que la mer
```

Think like it is near to `les yeux sont verts... comme la mer` which, I think, could help you to remember

Answer (score 1):

In such a construction, the adjective can only ever agree with the subject of *être*. So you want *verts* here. If it went the other way, it would be *La mer est plus **verte** que ses yeux* and so on.

Comment: If you refer to the exeample of *les yeux sont aussi verts que la mer", it should be *verts*, not *vertes*. A typo maybe ?

Comment: asdfghjkl for some reason in my head it was "larmes" instead of "yeux"